# Is there a script or tool that converts HTML to PDF?

Tags: software-rec, conversion

I want to convert an HTML page to PDF file.

I tried online converting tools but they are slow and I can't trust them.

Is there any script or tool works on the command line that convert web pages to PDF files?

Comment: Do you want to convert html to pdf or webp to pdf? webp is an image format so why would you try to convert it to pdf? For the former, have you looked at Google?

Comment: @NasirRiley i want to convert html to pdf. excuse my ignorance i thought that webp stands for web pages my bad, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Have you looked at any tools or methods to do this? The best way to get what you want is to research it and try it on your own.

Comment: i'll try to search for it, i just thought that asking here would be much easier than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ use the webkit engine to render HTML files to PDF.  You can also use [google chrome straight from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/592974/how-to-print-to-save-as-pdf-from-a-command-line-with-chrome-or-chromium)

Comment: print to pdf ..

Comment: " i just thought that asking here would be much easier than reinventing the wheel" Searching for something is not reinventing the wheel any more than asking. Often, it takes more time to ask your question than googling for an answer, in particular if you add the time for people to clarify your question and write the answer.

Comment: @zevzek I do not know what browser are you using and how do you print to PDF. I have never had problems with printing to PDF ending in a image only PDF. The PDFs I make with browser are always searchable as is HTML. If  page consists of images only, then it cannot work, but then you cannot search in HTML either. Any tool would need to render HTML and then print it. The best renderers are in browsers, so printing from there seems like the best option for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use open source tool called [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) , with pandoc you can convert your HTML file to many content types (Markdown, PDF , Latex , Etc ...)

simple command you can use for convert your file to pdf

```
$ pandoc yourfile.html -o yourhtmlbut.pdf
```

here all examples you can use in pandoc : https://pandoc.org/demos.html

for trust issue here the source code of pandoc : https://github.com/jgm/pandoc

Answer (score 1):

> I tried online converting tools but they are slow and I can't trust them.

This indicates that you wouldn't mind using your browser to solve the problem, if the solution didn't involve sending data to an untrusted third party, and worked reasonably fast.

Thus, instead of uploading your HTML to have it converted to PDF, what you do is load that HTML directly with your browser, and then print to PDF.